# What is the best way to implement AWS Lambda for async requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda function that potentially many different APIs call to parse large chunks of data (potentially might take more than a few minutes) and store their results into their own separate S3.

In such case, is it better to have a copy of the same AWS Lambda function separately for each API or is it ok to have the same lambda function being called from many APIs?

The goal is to avoid queuing and have the function run asynchronously for each request.
[visual reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1066V.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, so perhaps other answers will help more, but I don't see why it would make a difference as long as the code involved in processing each separate call isn't enough to increase the cost of initializing an instance.

The reason I don't think it would make a difference is that lambda will initialize a new instance if it is invoked while processing another function. This approach is potentially better because you can at times have an already initialized instance from a previous request ready for the next one (although again, I'm sure there are aws experts who could confirm/deny this, you should contact AWS support if you want an authoritative answer).

Source:

> If you invoke the function again while the first event is being processed, Lambda initializes another instance, and the function processes the two events concurrently. As more events come in, Lambda routes them to available instances and creates new instances as needed.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-scaling.html